# Prove that this infinite triangular matrix is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the linear operator $A: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ identified with the following matrix:
$$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/2 & 1/3 & \cdots \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/3 & \cdots \\
0 & 0   & 1/3 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
More formally:
$$
A=[a_{ij}]_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}, \qquad a_{ij}= \left\{ {\begin{array}{ll}
   1/j, & i\leq j  \\
   0,   & \textrm{else}  \\
\end{array}} \right.
$$
Can you prove that $A$ is a bounded operator ($\|A\| < \infty$)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It seems bounded by $2.$

Comment: @Aphyd I tried Schur's test, weighted Schur's test, bounding the norm with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, resolving the norm summation directly. I couldn't prove anything from any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of the matrix are finite, therefore the operator is well defined on the subspace  $\mathcal{F}\subset \ell^2$ consisting of sequences with finitely many nonzero terms. Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ denote the standard basis of $\ell^2.$ Then
$$\langle Ae_i,Ae_j\rangle =\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{ki}{a}_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^{\min(i,j)}{1\over ij}=\begin{cases} {1\over i} & j\le i\\
{1\over j} & j>i
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}\langle Ae_i, e_j\rangle & j\le i\\
\langle Ae_j,e_i\rangle & j>i
\end{cases}$$
Let $v\in \mathcal{F}.$ Then
$$\|Av\|_2^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \langle Ae_i,Ae_j\rangle v_i\overline{v}_j =\sum_{j\le i}\langle Ae_i,e_j\rangle v_i\overline{v}_j +\sum_{j\ge i}\langle Ae_j,e_i\rangle v_i\overline{v}_j -\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle |v_i|^2\\ =
\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty\langle Ae_i,e_j\rangle v_i\overline{v}_j +\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty\langle Ae_j,e_i\rangle v_i\overline{v}_j -\sum_{i=1}^\infty {1\over i}  |v_i|^2\\
=\langle Av,v\rangle +\overline{\langle Av,v\rangle} -\sum_{i=1}^\infty {1\over i} |v_i|^2 \le 2{\rm Re}\, \langle Av,v\rangle$$
Therefore, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get
$$\|Av\|_2^2\le 2\|Av\|_2\|v\|_2$$ hence $\|Av\|_2\le 2\|v\|_2.$ Finally we obtain $\|A\|\le 2.$

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the triangular sum equals $\left<Av,v\right>$?

Comment: The first, for example, triangular sum is actually a full double sum, as $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j.$ The double sum is equal $\langle Av,v\rangle .$

Comment: I have re-edited the answer to include the step with double sums which represent the quadratic forms.